# Java util zip creates "corrupt" zip files

Tags: java, zip

I'm zipping up the contents of a directory, but running into an error when trying to open the zipped up files.

Can anyone tell what's going on with my code? Perhaps I'm not allocating enough bytes?

Look inside zipDirectory() and you will see that I'm zipping up folders which contain special extension files.

Not sure where the error's occurring, so maybe someone can help me out there!

Much appreciated

```
    private void zipDirectory() {

       File lazyDirectory = new File(defaultSaveLocation);

       File[] files = lazyDirectory.listFiles();

       for (File file : files) {

          if (file.isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("Zipping up " + file);
            zipContents(file);
            }
        }       
    }


public static void addToZip(String fileName, ZipOutputStream zos) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    System.out.println("Writing '" + fileName + "' to zip file");

    File file = new File(fileName);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(fileName);
    zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);

    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
        zos.write(bytes, 0, length);
    }

    zos.closeEntry();
    fis.close();

    }

public static void zipContents(File dirToZip) {

    List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<File>();

    File[] filesToZip = dirToZip.listFiles();

    for (File zipThis : filesToZip) {

        String ext = "";

        int i = zipThis.toString().lastIndexOf('.');

        if (i > 0) {
            ext = zipThis.toString().substring(i+1);
        }

        if(ext.matches("cpp|bem|gz|h|hpp|pl|pln|ppcout|vec|xml|csv")){
            fileList.add(zipThis);
        }

    }


    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dirToZip.getName() + ".zip");
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);

        for (File file : fileList) {

            addToZip(file.toString(), zos);

        }

      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't you perform zos.close() after the last for?

Comment: I'd also be worried about this: `file.toString()`.  This says add the file "C:\some\dir\some\where\file.ext" to the zip file, using that path.  This means that when you come to unzip it, it will be unzipped to this EXACT location.  Better to try and build a relative path based on the original top level path (ie, trim of the root parent ;))

Comment: I never managed to get this working with the standard java utils. Dropping in Apache Commons Compress (and adding some archive closure calls) solved this for me. Also, make sure you wrap your input / output streams in buffered readers / writers.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Like most issues with IO streams in Java, your fault is almost certainly that you are not closing the streams properly. You need to add:

```
zos.finish(); // good practice
zos.close();
```

after the for loop.

Comment: maybe you mean `flush`. Anyway, I vote for Pioevezan's comment.

Comment: No, I mean 'finish()'. In the case of a ZipOutputStream, finish() is different to flush().

Comment: I was doing this, but my problem turned out to be that I was attempting to do something with the zip file before I closed the output stream.

Comment: This answer was the solution for me. `finish()` writes the central directory to the end of the zip file, as zips have their metadata at the end of the file. 7z, and other zip programs are able to work without this directory, but it seems that windows expects it.

Comment: It is bad practice to call `finish()` here, not good practice. The code of `ZipOutputStream` literally invokes `finish()` as part of `close()`. If this is 'good practice', then you should also be advocating that sticking `import java.lang.*;` at the top of all source files is 'good practice'. No it isn't: Stating the obvious is not good practice. Just adding a `.finish()` call immediately preceding a `close()` call cannot possibly solve any problems.

Comment: @IanGabes what you're missing is that you have to close the underlying resource anyway (or the file would be half-written, for example), and `ZipOutputStream`'s `close()` method calls `finish()` as part of its operation. Therefore, you cannot possibly have that be 'the solution for me', unless you weren't calling close or weren't calling it correctly (e.g. not in a try-with-resources construct for example). The real fix is to call close properly, __not__ to call `finish()`. Finish() on its own is broken code that might occasionally work. Which is worse, as that just _hard to test_ broken code.

Comment: @rzwitserloot keep in mind that this is Java code from 2013. it is possible that back then close() didn't call finish().

Comment: @Nzall No, [it did](https://github.com/keerath/openjdk-8-source/blob/master/jdk/src/share/classes/java/util/zip/DeflaterOutputStream.java#L238).

Answer (score 3):

For me the fix is that you need to do this for **EVERY** file entry

```
zos.finish()
zos.flush()
zos.closeEntry()
```

Then do the above things again to close the `zos`. Otherwise, the default windows can't open the zipped folder properly, but third-party application works.

Comment: for me `closeEntry()` for every entry and `flush()` + `finish()` before closing the entire stream worked

Comment: Unless things were very different in 2017, both this answer as well as the top comment by `hello_earth` __cannot possibly be correct__ - because `putNextEntry` literally calls `closeEntry()` as very first act. `finish()` does do stuff. Specifically: finish _the entire ZIP file. Calling `finish()` ends the entire zip file; calling it and then adding another entry is broken__. Do not follow the advice given in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

This may also happen if you use a character-oriented writer (e.g. FileWriter) to create the unzipped files (that actually contain binary data)

I was unable to read files that I was extracting and switching to a binary output stream (FileOutputStream) fixed the issue