# ZipCompressor utility class sometimes produces invalid archives

Tags: java, zip, corruption

I have the following ZipCompressor Java class:

```
package lib.util.compressors.zip;

import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import lib.util.compressors.Compressor;
import lib.util.compressors.CompressorException;
import lib.util.compressors.Entry;

import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

/**
 * The ZipCompressor class supplies a simple way of writing zip files. The default zip level is set
 * to maximum compression.
 * 
 * @author REDACTED
 */
public class ZipCompressor extends Compressor {

    private int zipLevel = 9;

    /**
     * @see lib.util.compressors.Compressor#compress
     */
    public void compress(String fileName, String dirName) throws CompressorException {

        File zipFile = new File(fileName);
        try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
                ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
                ) {

            // Open the file and set the compression level
            zos.setLevel(zipLevel);

            // Zip the directory
            File dir = new File(dirName);
            compress(zipFile, zos, dir, dir);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            throw new CompressorException(fnfe);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new CompressorException(ioe);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see lib.util.compressors.Compressor#uncompress
     */
    public void uncompress(String fileName, String dirName) throws CompressorException {

        try(// Open the zipfile
            ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(fileName);
                // Open streams
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(zipFile.getName());
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(bis);) {

            
            // Get the size of each entry
            Map<String, Integer> zipEntrySizes = new HashMap<String, Integer> ();
            Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> e = zipFile.entries();
            while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
                ZipEntry zipEntry = (ZipEntry) e.nextElement();
                zipEntrySizes.put(zipEntry.getName(), Integer.valueOf((int) zipEntry.getSize()));
            }

            
            // Start reading zipentries
            ZipEntry zipEntry = null;
            while ((zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                
                // Zipentry is a file
                if (!zipEntry.isDirectory()) {

                    // Get the size
                    int size = (int) zipEntry.getSize();
                    if (size == -1) {
                        size = ((Integer) zipEntrySizes.get(zipEntry.getName())).intValue();
                    }

                    // Get the content
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                    int bytesInBuffer = 0;
                    int bytesRead = 0;
                    while (((int) size - bytesInBuffer) > 0) {
                        bytesRead = zis.read(buffer, bytesInBuffer, size - bytesInBuffer);
                        if (bytesRead == -1) {
                            break;
                        }
                        bytesInBuffer += bytesRead;
                    }

                    String zipEntryName = zipEntry.getName();
                    // replace all "\" with "/"
                    zipEntryName = zipEntryName.replace('\\', '/');

                    // Get the full path name
                    File file = new File(dirName, zipEntryName);

                    // Create the parent directory
                    if (!file.getParentFile().exists()) {
                        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                    }

                    // Save file
                    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file.getPath());) {
                        fos.write(buffer, 0, bytesInBuffer);
                    }

                    if (zipEntry.getTime() >= 0L) {
                        // Set modification date to the date in the zipEntry
                        file.setLastModified(zipEntry.getTime());
                    }
                }
                // Zipentry is a directory
                else {

                    String zipEntryName = zipEntry.getName();
                    // replace all "\" with "/"
                    zipEntryName = zipEntryName.replace('\\', '/');

                    // Create the directory
                    File dir = new File(dirName, zipEntryName);
                    dir.setLastModified(zipEntry.getTime());
                    if (!dir.exists()) {
                        dir.mkdirs();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new CompressorException(ioe);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see lib.util.compressors.Compressor#getEntries
     */
    public List<Entry> getEntries(String fileName, boolean calculateCrc) throws CompressorException {

        // List to return all entries
        List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        
        try( // Open the zipfile
                ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(fileName);) {

           
            // Get the size of each entry
            Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> e = zipFile.entries();
            while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
                ZipEntry zipEntry = (ZipEntry) e.nextElement();
                Entry entry = new Entry();
                entry.setName(zipEntry.getName());
                if (calculateCrc) {
                    entry.setCrc(zipEntry.getCrc());
                } else {
                    entry.setCrc(-1);
                }
                entry.setDirectory(zipEntry.isDirectory());
                entry.setTime(zipEntry.getTime());
                entry.setSize(zipEntry.getSize());
                entries.add(entry);
            }

        
            // Sort entries by ascending name
            sortEntries(entries);
            
            // Return entries
            return entries;
            
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new CompressorException(ioe);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets the zip level (1..9).
     * 
     * @param zipLevel the desired zip level.
     * @throws CompressorException
     */
    public void setZipLevel(int zipLevel) throws CompressorException {
        if ((zipLevel < 1) || (zipLevel > 9)) {
            throw new CompressorException("Zip level " + zipLevel + " out of range (0 ... 9)");
        }
        this.zipLevel = zipLevel;
    }

    /**
     * Add a new entry to the zip file.
     * 
     * @param zos the output stream filter for writing files in the ZIP file format
     * @param name the name of the entry.
     * @param lastModified the modification date 
     * @param buffer an array of bytes
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void addEntry(ZipOutputStream zos, String name, long lastModified, byte[] buffer) throws IOException {
        ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(name);
        if (buffer != null) {
            zipEntry.setSize(buffer.length);
        } 
        zipEntry.setTime(lastModified);
        zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
        if (buffer != null) {
            zos.write(buffer);
        }
        zos.closeEntry();
    }

    /**
     * Zip the files of the given directory.
     * 
     * @param zipFile the File which is used to store the compressed data
     * @param zos the output stream filter for writing files in the ZIP file format
     * @param dir the directory to zip
     * @param relativeDir the name of each zip entry will be relative to this directory
     * @throws FileNotFoundException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void compress(File zipFile, ZipOutputStream zos, File dir, File relativeDir) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        // Create an array of File objects
        File[] fileList = dir.listFiles();

        // Directory is not empty
        if (fileList.length != 0) {

            // Loop through File array
            for (int i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {

                // The zipfile itself may not be added
                if (!zipFile.equals(fileList[i])) {
                    // Directory
                    if (fileList[i].isDirectory()) {
                        compress(zipFile, zos, fileList[i], relativeDir);
                    }
                    // File
                    else {
                        byte[] buffer = getFileContents(fileList[i]);
                        if (buffer != null) {
                            // Get the path names
                            String filePath = fileList[i].getPath();
                            String relativeDirPath = relativeDir.getPath();

                            // Convert the absolute path name to a relative path name
                            if (filePath.startsWith(relativeDirPath)) {
                                filePath = filePath.substring(relativeDirPath.length());
                                if (filePath.startsWith("/") || filePath.startsWith("\\")) {
                                    if (filePath.length() == 1) {
                                        filePath = "";
                                    } else {
                                        filePath = filePath.substring(1);
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            // Add the entry
                            addEntry(zos, filePath, fileList[i].lastModified(), buffer);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // Directory is empty
        else {
            // Get the path names
            String filePath = dir.getPath();
            String relativeDirPath = relativeDir.getPath();

            // Convert the absolute path name to a relative path name
            if (filePath.startsWith(relativeDirPath)) {
                filePath = filePath.substring(relativeDirPath.length());
                if (filePath.startsWith("/") || filePath.startsWith("\\")) {
                    if (filePath.length() == 1) {
                        filePath = "";
                    } else {
                        filePath = filePath.substring(1);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Add the entry
            if (!filePath.endsWith("\\") && !filePath.endsWith("/")) {
                addEntry(zos, filePath + "/", dir.lastModified(), null);
            }
            else {
                addEntry(zos, filePath, dir.lastModified(), null);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Read the contents of a file for zipping.
     * 
     * @param file the File to read
     * @return an array of bytes
     * @throws FileNotFoundException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private byte[] getFileContents(File file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);) {
            long len = file.length();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) len];
            fis.read(buffer);
            return buffer;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that sometimes the compress() method produces an invalid archive with an incorrectly compressed first entry, that can't be opened by Windows or Java 11 and shows errors when opened with 7zip.

In Java, the error code I get is:

```
lib.util.compressors.CompressorException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid END header (bad central directory offset)
    at lib.util.compressors.zip.ZipCompressor.uncompress(ZipCompressor.java:151)
    at phases.core.deploy.UnCompressBuildResultPhase.execute(UnCompressBuildResultPhase.java:61)
    at Proxy6f3235bf_85bf_485a_9577_a60fb3dad49c.execute(Unknown Source)
    at phases.impl.DefaultPhaseExecutionImpl.execute(DefaultPhaseExecutionImpl.java:152)
    at daemons.agent.deployer.DeployerThread.run(DeployerThread.java:144)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid END header (bad central directory offset)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.zerror(ZipFile.java:1607)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1519)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.<init>(ZipFile.java:1308)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1271)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:733)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.get(ZipFile.java:850)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:148)
    at lib.util.compressors.zip.ZipCompressor.uncompress(ZipCompressor.java:72)
    ... 4 more
```

The 7zip errors it shows when testing the archive are:

```
C:\Users\REDACTED\Downloads\b5_CONTBUILD_B-6-0-0_win.zip
Unavailable start of archive
Warning
The archive is open with offset
Unavailable data : ant\bin\ant
```

And the properties of the archive as 7zip gives them are:

```
Path: C:\Users\REDACTED\Downloads\b5_CONTBUILD_B-6-0-0_win.zip
Type: zip
Open WARNING:: Cannot open the file as expected archive type
Error Type: zip
Errors: Unavailable start of archive
Offset: -1024
Physical Size: 722 598 855
```

This is a transient error, in that it doesn't happen every time I try to create the same archive. However, when it happened the previous time, the error in the 7zip properties was slightly different:

```
Path: C:\Users\REDACTED\Downloads\b2355_CONTBUILD_win (1).zip
Type: zip
Open WARNING:: Cannot open the file as expected archive type
Error Type: zip
Errors: Unavailable start of archive
Offset: -256
Physical Size: 712 638 486
```

Note that both of these archives were generated using a Java 11.0.1.9 JVM.

Usually rerunning the script fixes it, but the entire script can take up to an hour to complete, of which the archive creation is only a small part.

I found some information on [Java util zip creates "corrupt" zip files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17055650/java-util-zip-creates-corrupt-zip-files) that says I should call zos.finish() and zos.flush() at the end of the try-with-resources, but if I'm not mistaken, zos.close() already calls those methods.

Edit: As I said above, I already found that question recommended as duplicate, I even linked it above, and to the best of my knowledge the code I currently use already does what that answer recommends, because the try-with-resources already automatically closes the ZipOutputStream using close(), and close() calls finish(). I didn't check the full stack call to verify, but I think .flush() is also called somewhere in that close stack.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your entire code is too big for this question. Also have you tried to use any of the methods you mentioned? Neither of them are in your code.

Comment: What's the relevance of the uncompress code? And I notice you don't check the return value of `FileInputStream.read`.

Comment: @tgdavies I had something happen while creating this question and lost my original question and had to recreate it. During that time I forgot to include the error I got when calling the uncompress code. As for the FileInputStream.read() return value part, I didn't touch that part when I last changed the code. The last change I made to this code was to use try-with-resources every time there used to be a try-finally.

Comment: Your `getFileContents` method is just plain broken, the setup means it'll fail on large files, the security setup of ensuring no absolute paths end up in the zip file is dubious, and the exception handling is problematic. However, none of these issues explain what you are observing. Given that it occurs intermittently, and no obvious issues are in the code that explain it (you're right, you're closing the right things safely):

Comment: [1] Write test code that uses this class to write a bunch of reliably-random data (reliably random: Generate it using `new Random(1234)` - some hardcoded seed value, so that every run it's the same) and run it a few times. Preferably in a script loop (using its own unzip code to check if did the job right). Your first job is to have a setup where you can reliably cause the problem to re-occur. And in considerably less time than an hour.

Comment: [2] Then run it with `-Xint` and run it on Java17. Then run it on a different disk (a failing disk would also explain this, though you'd expect more problems to show up on your system if that's the explanation).

Comment: This seems to be a duplicated of [Java util zip creates "corrupt" zip files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17055650/java-util-zip-creates-corrupt-zip-files) and you just didn't follow the instructions of the answer in your code.

Comment: @aled If you want to post a rather aggressive 'RTFM' style instruction perhaps put some effort in before becoming part of the meme that SO just directs you to an unrelated question or otherwise tells you to take a hike. OP is _already_ doing what that other answer says to do and _still_ runs into the problem.

Comment: @Nzall The question you linked to has 4 answers on it and they are all completely incorrect. Even the 34 upvote accepted one. You're right to ignore those. This is one of those places Stack Overflow just utterly fails. As per policy I'm supposed to mark this as dupe of that, but that 34-upvote checked answer cannot be overcome without a botnet. Hence I refuse to VTC this. I wish I could help you more.

Comment: @rzwitserloot OP code doesn't has any mention of zos.finish() and the question doesn't mention they tried to use them. They should at least try the method of the answer they mentioned.

Comment: @aled zos.finish() gets called by zos.close() internally (or rather, zos.close() internally calls super.close(), and the superclass close method calls finish() which gets delegated to zos.finish. zos.close() is automatically called at the end of the try-with-resources in compress().

Comment: @aled `close()` calls finish. Just open the ZipOutputStream source and check for yourself. I have also added a comment on the question you linked to (__every__ answer there is completely wrong. Unfortunate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some additional testing, I have found that in fact the cause is NOT the Zip compression step. This code runs as part of a longer series of steps of which the compression step is one, and the step directly afterwards copies the created archive to another directory on a different drive. I have now verified that the archive before copying does work fine, but the archive AFTER copying doesn't. Hence the ZipCompressor does not seem related to this problem.

Comment: How is the file being copied? It doesn't make sense that the original would be okay but the copy not okay.

Comment: @kensei62 I did some additional testing since then and it appeared to be related to the Acronis Cyber Protect antivirus software: when I disabled it (or as much of it as I could anyway) the copy always worked.

Answer (score -2):

Based on the information and the code you provided, it seems that the issue might be related to the usage of zos.close() and zos.closeEntry() inside the compress method. The ZipOutputStream needs to be properly closed after writing the data, but it's also essential to close each entry before adding a new one. The close() method alone might not be sufficient in this case.

To fix the problem, you should modify the compress method to ensure that you properly close each entry after writing its contents. You can achieve this by moving the zos.closeEntry() call outside the inner loop. Here's the updated version of the compress method:

private void compress(File zipFile, ZipOutputStream zos, File dir, File relativeDir) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
// ... existing code ...

```
for (int i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
    // ... existing code ...

    if (!zipFile.equals(fileList[i])) {
        if (fileList[i].isDirectory()) {
            compress(zipFile, zos, fileList[i], relativeDir);
        } else {
            byte[] buffer = getFileContents(fileList[i]);
            if (buffer != null) {
                // ... existing code ...

                // Add the entry
                addEntry(zos, filePath, fileList[i].lastModified(), buffer);
            }
        }
    }
}

// Move this outside the loop to properly close the ZipOutputStream after writing all entries
zos.closeEntry();
```

}

By moving zos.closeEntry() outside the inner loop, you ensure that each entry is closed before adding the next one. This should help in producing valid and correctly compressed zip archives.

Additionally, you are correct that the zos.close() call in the try-with-resources block should take care of calling zos.finish() and zos.flush(). So, you don't need to call these methods separately.

Change to your ZipCompressor class, and it should help resolve the issue with invalid archives.

Comment: I already call zos.closeEntry() at the end of the addEntry() method. Do I really need to call it again outside the for loop then as well?

Comment: Yes you need call again outside the for loop

Comment: [A] OP already does that, [B] The docs state clearly that `.putNextEntry` also closes the previous, and `close()` closes the last open entry. If this was the explanation, then you'd have seen it _reliably_ fail, instead of intermittently.